# JOOQ optimistic locking and DataChangedException: Database record has been changed on record.update

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, jooq, yugabytedb

**Summary of the problem:**

I have a `case class Test04(...)` with values from e.g. mobile client to be updated into db. Table uses `tSt` field of type `timestamptz` for optimistic locking and the `tSt` value is the current value in the db.
So I have unique id and up to date `tSt`. So it should be possible to update the values in the db.

The case class is transformed to `RecordTest04` to make db operations shorter: `record.update()` instead of DSL statement which I have to modify manually every time a new field is added/removed into/from the table.

For some reason the `record.update()` throws `org.jooq.exception.DataChangedException: Database record has been changed`

**Details:**

I have following sql:

```
-- for table04
create or replace function createUuid() returns uuid
    as 'SELECT md5(random()::text || clock_timestamp()::text)::uuid;'
    language sql
    stable;


create or replace function insertUuidT()
returns trigger as
$BODY$
begin
    if new.id is null then
        new.id = createUuid();
    end if;
    new.tSt = now();
    return new;
end
$BODY$
language 'plpgsql';


create or replace function updatePreventT()
returns trigger as
$BODY$
begin
    if new.id <> old.id then
        raise exception 'You cannot modify id. Current id: % Proposed id: %', OLD.id, NEW.id; -- USING ERRCODE='123';
    end if;
    new.tSt = now();
    return new;
end
$BODY$
language 'plpgsql';


drop table if exists test04 cascade;

create table test04 (
    id uuid not null,                               -- Unique, link to other tables
    intNotNull int not null,
    dateNotNull date not null,
    dateNull date,
    timestamptzNotNull timestamptz not null,
    timestamptzNull timestamptz,
    tSt timestamptz not null,                       -- timestamp for optimistic locking support
    primary key ( id )
);

create unique index test04_id on test04( id );

drop trigger if exists test04_insert ON test04;
create trigger test04_insert before insert on test04 for each row execute procedure insertUuidT(); --setUuid();

drop trigger if exists test04_update ON test04;
create trigger test04_update before update on test04 for each row execute procedure updatePreventT(); --preventIdChange();
```

DB settings are:

```
  val settings = new Settings()
    .withExecuteWithOptimisticLocking(true) // Defaults to false
    .withUpdatablePrimaryKeys(true) // Defaults to false, primary keys are not always internal
    .withReturnAllOnUpdatableRecord(true) // Defaults to false, return all db/JOOQ generated values.
    .withMapJPAAnnotations(false) // Defaults to true, annotations are not used
    //.withExecuteWithOptimisticLockingExcludeUnversioned(true) // Defaults to false

  val sqlDialect = SQLDialect.POSTGRES

  val jdbcDriverClass = Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")
```

And the code is:

```
  val connection = JooqTestConnectionPool.dataSource.getConnection
  val db = DBSettings.getDSLContext(connection) // Using Conf to create DSL.

  val uuid1 = UUID.fromString("0c6e629b-aa0c-43eb-82fd-645c565a689a")
  val t04_1 = Test04(uuid1, 1230, LocalDate.now(), Some(LocalDate.now().minusDays(100)), OffsetDateTime.now(), Some(OffsetDateTime.now().minusMinutes(10)),OffsetDateTime.now())

  db.deleteFrom(TEST04).where(TEST04.ID.eq(uuid1)).execute()

  val t04_1RecA = db.newRecord(TEST04, t04_1)
  val t04_1RecB = db.newRecord(TEST04, t04_1)
  println(s"t04_1RecA before insert\n${t04_1RecA}")
  val iResA = t04_1RecA.insert()
  println(s"t04_1RecA after insert\n${t04_1RecA}")
  if (iResA != 1) throw new RuntimeException(s"Invalid insert res A: ${iResA}")

  t04_1RecB.changed("id",false)
  t04_1RecB.setIntnotnull(800)
  t04_1RecB.setTst(t04_1RecA.getTst)
  println(s"t04_1RecB before update\n${t04_1RecB}")
  t04_1RecB.update() // -> This will cause org.jooq.exception.DataChangedException: Database record has been changed
  println(s"t04_1RecB after update\n${t04_1RecB}")

  connection.close()
```

Runtime output is:

```
Thank you for using jOOQ 3.12.4

Executing query          : delete from "public"."test04" where "public"."test04"."id" = cast(? as uuid)
-> with bind values      : delete from "public"."test04" where "public"."test04"."id" = '0c6e629b-aa0c-43eb-82fd-645c565a689a'
Affected row(s)          : 1
t04_1RecA before insert
+-------------------------------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|id                                   |intnotnull|datenotnull|datenull         |timestamptznotnull               |timestamptznull                        |tst                              |
+-------------------------------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|*0c6e629b-aa0c-43eb-82fd-645c565a689a|     *1230|*2020-06-12|*Some(2020-03-04)|*2020-06-12T15:59:39.655505+03:00|*Some(2020-06-12T15:49:39.655508+03:00)|*2020-06-12T15:59:39.655514+03:00|
+-------------------------------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------+

Executing query          : insert into "public"."test04" ("id", "intnotnull", "datenotnull", "datenull", "timestamptznotnull", "timestamptznull", "tst") values (cast(? as uuid), ?, cast(? as date), cast(? as date), cast(? as timestamp with time zone), cast(? as timestamp with time zone), cast(? as timestamp with time zone)) returning "public"."test04"."id", "public"."test04"."intnotnull", "public"."test04"."datenotnull", "public"."test04"."datenull", "public"."test04"."timestamptznotnull", "public"."test04"."timestamptznull", "public"."test04"."tst"
-> with bind values      : insert into "public"."test04" ("id", "intnotnull", "datenotnull", "datenull", "timestamptznotnull", "timestamptznull", "tst") values ('0c6e629b-aa0c-43eb-82fd-645c565a689a', 1230, date '2020-06-12', date '2020-03-04', timestamp with time zone '2020-06-12 15:59:39.655505+03:00', timestamp with time zone '2020-06-12 15:49:39.655508+03:00', timestamp with time zone '2020-06-12 15:59:39.655514+03:00') returning "public"."test04"."id", "public"."test04"."intnotnull", "public"."test04"."datenotnull", "public"."test04"."datenull", "public"."test04"."timestamptznotnull", "public"."test04"."timestamptznull", "public"."test04"."tst"
 Fetched result           : +------------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
                          : |id                                  |intnotnull|datenotnull|datenull        |timestamptznotnull              |timestamptznull                       |tst                             |
                          : +------------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
                          : |0c6e629b-aa0c-43eb-82fd-645c565a689a|      1230|2020-06-12 |Some(2020-03-04)|2020-06-12T15:59:39.655505+03:00|Some(2020-06-12T15:49:39.655508+03:00)|2020-06-12T15:59:40.181434+03:00|
                          : +------------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
 Fetched row(s)           : 1
t04_1RecA after insert
+------------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|id                                  |intnotnull|datenotnull|datenull        |timestamptznotnull              |timestamptznull                       |tst                             |
+------------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|0c6e629b-aa0c-43eb-82fd-645c565a689a|      1230|2020-06-12 |Some(2020-03-04)|2020-06-12T15:59:39.655505+03:00|Some(2020-06-12T15:49:39.655508+03:00)|2020-06-12T15:59:40.181434+03:00|
+------------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+

t04_1RecB before update
+------------------------------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|id                                  |intnotnull|datenotnull|datenull         |timestamptznotnull               |timestamptznull                        |tst                              |
+------------------------------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|0c6e629b-aa0c-43eb-82fd-645c565a689a|      *800|*2020-06-12|*Some(2020-03-04)|*2020-06-12T15:59:39.655505+03:00|*Some(2020-06-12T15:49:39.655508+03:00)|*2020-06-12T15:59:40.181434+03:00|
+------------------------------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------+

 Executing query          : select "public"."test04"."id", "public"."test04"."intnotnull", "public"."test04"."datenotnull", "public"."test04"."datenull", "public"."test04"."timestamptznotnull", "public"."test04"."timestamptznull", "public"."test04"."tst" from "public"."test04" where "public"."test04"."id" = cast(? as uuid) for update
 -> with bind values      : select "public"."test04"."id", "public"."test04"."intnotnull", "public"."test04"."datenotnull", "public"."test04"."datenull", "public"."test04"."timestamptznotnull", "public"."test04"."timestamptznull", "public"."test04"."tst" from "public"."test04" where "public"."test04"."id" = '0c6e629b-aa0c-43eb-82fd-645c565a689a' for update
 Fetched result           : +------------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
                          : |id                                  |intnotnull|datenotnull|datenull        |timestamptznotnull              |timestamptznull                       |tst                             |
                          : +------------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
                          : |0c6e629b-aa0c-43eb-82fd-645c565a689a|      1230|2020-06-12 |Some(2020-03-04)|2020-06-12T15:59:39.655505+03:00|Some(2020-06-12T15:49:39.655508+03:00)|2020-06-12T15:59:40.181434+03:00|
                          : +------------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
 Fetched row(s)           : 1
 Concurrent update 1 1677ms 
  org.jooq.exception.DataChangedException: Database record has been changed
    org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl.checkIfChanged(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:427)
    org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl.storeUpdate0(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:247)
```

Problem is that `t04_1RecB.update()` throws exception although the `tst` field used for optimistic locking is copied from db immediately before update.

If I use `.withExecuteWithOptimisticLockingExcludeUnversioned(true)` then the update does not fail but then the update does not use `tst` column to detect out of date updates.

Comment: There's an issue related to timestamp precision: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9933 Could that be it?

Answer (score 0):

I did some further testing on this issue with two tables. First table (test07) had `timestamp` type column for optimistic locking. JOOQ documentation mentions `int` and `timestamp` types for optimistic locking field. In my original environment optimistic locking column was of type `timestamptz`.
However this did not cure the problem. Exactly same exception is thrown.

The second table (test03) had `int` column for optimistic locking:

```
-- for table 03
create or replace function insertUuidVerT()
returns trigger as
$BODY$
begin
    if new.id is null then
        new.id = createUuid();
    end if;
    new.ver = 0;
    return new;
end
$BODY$
language 'plpgsql';


create or replace function updatePreventVerT()
returns trigger as
$BODY$
begin
    if new.id <> old.id then
        raise exception 'You cannot modify id. Current id: % Proposed id: %', OLD.id, NEW.id; -- USING ERRCODE='123';
    end if;
    new.ver = old.ver + 1;
    return new;
end
$BODY$
language 'plpgsql';


drop table if exists test03 cascade;

create table test03 (
    id uuid not null,                               -- Unique, link to other tables
    intNotNull int not null,
    dateNotNull date not null,
    dateNull date,
    timestamptzNotNull timestamptz not null,
    timestamptzNull timestamptz,
    ver int not null default 0,                     -- version for optimistic locking support
    primary key ( id )
);

drop trigger if exists test03_insert ON test03;
create trigger test03_insert before insert on test03 for each row execute procedure insertUuidVerT(); --setUuid();

drop trigger if exists test03_update ON test03;
create trigger test03_update before update on test03 for each row execute procedure updatePreventVerT(); --preventIdChange();
```

JOOQ settings where same as previously and the scala code was:

```
  val connection = JooqTestConnectionPool.dataSource.getConnection
  val db = DBSettings.getDSLContext(connection) //conf) // Using Conf to create DSL.

  val t03_1 = Test03(UUID.fromString("0bec53ff-91cb-47be-8318-14dd298e1d00"), 1230, LocalDate.now(), Some(LocalDate.now()), OffsetDateTime.now(), Some(OffsetDateTime.now()), null)

  db.deleteFrom(TEST03).where(TEST03.ID.eq(t03_1.id)).execute()

  val t03_1RecA = db.newRecord(TEST03, t03_1)
  val t03_1RecB = db.newRecord(TEST03, t03_1) // Identical id values
  println(s"t03_1RecA before insert\n${t03_1RecA}")
  val iResA = t03_1RecA.insert()
  println(s"t03_1RecA after insert\n${t03_1RecA}")
  if (iResA != 1) throw new RuntimeException(s"Invalid insert res A: ${iResA}")

  t03_1RecB.changed("id",false) // Does not work without this
  t03_1RecB.setIntnotnull(800)
  t03_1RecB.setVer(t03_1RecA.getVer)
  t03_1RecB.changed("ver",false) // Does not work without this
  println(s"t03_1RecB before update\n${t03_1RecB}")
  t03_1RecB.update()
  println(s"t03_1RecB after update\n${t03_1RecB}")

  connection.close()
```

Runtime output:

```
 Executing query          : insert into "public"."test03" ("id", "intnotnull", "datenotnull", "datenull", "timestamptznotnull", "timestamptznull", "ver") values (cast(? as uuid), ?, cast(? as date), cast(? as date), cast(? as timestamp with time zone), cast(? as timestamp with time zone), ?) returning "public"."test03"."id", "public"."test03"."intnotnull", "public"."test03"."datenotnull", "public"."test03"."datenull", "public"."test03"."timestamptznotnull", "public"."test03"."timestamptznull", "public"."test03"."ver"
 -> with bind values      : insert into "public"."test03" ("id", "intnotnull", "datenotnull", "datenull", "timestamptznotnull", "timestamptznull", "ver") values ('0bec53ff-91cb-47be-8318-14dd298e1d00', 1230, date '2020-06-13', date '2020-06-13', timestamp with time zone '2020-06-13 16:12:49.455824+03:00', timestamp with time zone '2020-06-13 16:12:49.455849+03:00', 1) returning "public"."test03"."id", "public"."test03"."intnotnull", "public"."test03"."datenotnull", "public"."test03"."datenull", "public"."test03"."timestamptznotnull", "public"."test03"."timestamptznull", "public"."test03"."ver"
 Fetched result           : +------------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+
                          : |id                                  |intnotnull|datenotnull|datenull        |timestamptznotnull              |timestamptznull                       | ver|
                          : +------------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+
                          : |0bec53ff-91cb-47be-8318-14dd298e1d00|      1230|2020-06-13 |Some(2020-06-13)|2020-06-13T16:12:49.455824+03:00|Some(2020-06-13T16:12:49.455849+03:00)|   0|
                          : +------------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+
 Fetched row(s)           : 1
t03_1RecA after insert
+------------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+
|id                                  |intnotnull|datenotnull|datenull        |timestamptznotnull              |timestamptznull                       | ver|
+------------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+
|0bec53ff-91cb-47be-8318-14dd298e1d00|      1230|2020-06-13 |Some(2020-06-13)|2020-06-13T16:12:49.455824+03:00|Some(2020-06-13T16:12:49.455849+03:00)|   0|
+------------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+

t03_1RecB before update
+------------------------------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------------+----+
|id                                  |intnotnull|datenotnull|datenull         |timestamptznotnull               |timestamptznull                        | ver|
+------------------------------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------------+----+
|0bec53ff-91cb-47be-8318-14dd298e1d00|      *800|*2020-06-13|*Some(2020-06-13)|*2020-06-13T16:12:49.455824+03:00|*Some(2020-06-13T16:12:49.455849+03:00)|   0|
+------------------------------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------------+----+

 Executing query          : update "public"."test03" set "intnotnull" = ?, "datenotnull" = cast(? as date), "datenull" = cast(? as date), "timestamptznotnull" = cast(? as timestamp with time zone), "timestamptznull" = cast(? as timestamp with time zone), "ver" = ? where ("public"."test03"."id" = cast(? as uuid) and "public"."test03"."ver" = ?) returning "public"."test03"."id", "public"."test03"."intnotnull", "public"."test03"."datenotnull", "public"."test03"."datenull", "public"."test03"."timestamptznotnull", "public"."test03"."timestamptznull", "public"."test03"."ver"
 -> with bind values      : update "public"."test03" set "intnotnull" = 800, "datenotnull" = date '2020-06-13', "datenull" = date '2020-06-13', "timestamptznotnull" = timestamp with time zone '2020-06-13 16:12:49.455824+03:00', "timestamptznull" = timestamp with time zone '2020-06-13 16:12:49.455849+03:00', "ver" = 1 where ("public"."test03"."id" = '0bec53ff-91cb-47be-8318-14dd298e1d00' and "public"."test03"."ver" = 0) returning "public"."test03"."id", "public"."test03"."intnotnull", "public"."test03"."datenotnull", "public"."test03"."datenull", "public"."test03"."timestamptznotnull", "public"."test03"."timestamptznull", "public"."test03"."ver"
 Fetched result           : +------------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+
                          : |id                                  |intnotnull|datenotnull|datenull        |timestamptznotnull              |timestamptznull                       | ver|
                          : +------------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+
                          : |0bec53ff-91cb-47be-8318-14dd298e1d00|       800|2020-06-13 |Some(2020-06-13)|2020-06-13T16:12:49.455824+03:00|Some(2020-06-13T16:12:49.455849+03:00)|   1|
                          : +------------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+
 Fetched row(s)           : 1
t03_1RecB after update
+------------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+
|id                                  |intnotnull|datenotnull|datenull        |timestamptznotnull              |timestamptznull                       | ver|
+------------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+
|0bec53ff-91cb-47be-8318-14dd298e1d00|       800|2020-06-13 |Some(2020-06-13)|2020-06-13T16:12:49.455824+03:00|Some(2020-06-13T16:12:49.455849+03:00)|   1|
+------------------------------------+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+
```

So it seems that when using `int` type optimistic locking field this exception does not occur but if using `timestamptz` or `timestamp` field it will for some reason occur.

Replacing `timestamptz` with `int` is one solution but I would still like to understand what is the problem with the `timestamptz`.

Answer (score 0):

Great investigation! Not sure if this is the intended semantics - there should not be anything special about the `timestampz` datatype. Could you please open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/YugaByte/yugabyte-db/issues) for this and we will take a look?